# what is the meaning of 'P' in tcpdump outout?

Tags: udp, tcpdump

---

I am using `tcpdump -i eth0 udp` cmd to sniff packets on an Ubuntu 22.04 system, and here is the output.

```
07:26:49.735591 eth_2_1 In  IP 192.168.1.1.ntp > 10.0.3.2.ntp: NTPv6, symmetric active, length 1
07:26:49.735600 eth_2_4 Out IP 192.168.1.1.ntp > 10.0.3.2.ntp: NTPv6, symmetric active, length 1
07:26:59.263240 eth_2_1 P   IP 192.168.1.1.12322 > 200.210.4.0.12322: UDP, length 1
```

I assume the `In` and `Out` suggest the weather the interface is sending or receiving that packet, but what is letter `P` suggesting?

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/972875/meaning-of-tcpdump-p-direction. First hit when searching for [tcpdump in out p](https://www.google.com/search?q=tcpdump+in+out+p)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was trying to find it in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Meanings of the packet type field:

```
In - packet addressed to host
Out - outgoing packet
B - broadcast
M - multicast
P - packet addressed to other host
```

Source: https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpdump/blob/master/print-sll.c#L142